# ios managing authentication tokens from NSURLRequest / HTTP request

Tags: iphone, ios, authentication, token, nsurlrequest

When I make a POST request to sign in from within the iPhone app I am developing, the request returns an authentication token that I can successfully store in an NSString to be used throughout the rest of the app.

However, for any request after the sign in, I must pass it this authentication token so the request knows that a user is logged in. What is the complete way to do this for an NSURLRequest / what parameters/values must i specify for the NSURLRequest? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

These NSURLRequest methods might help you

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"yoururl.com"]]; 
[request setHTTPMethod: @"POST" ];
[request setValue:@"yourtoken" forHTTPHeaderField:@"header field"];
[request setHTTPBody: dataifneeded ];
```